How to find probabilities that minimize the Helstrom Bound?
Suppose $\rho_{0}$ and $\rho_{1}$ are both density matrices in a $2^{N}$ dimensional Hilbert space. I want to minimize the quantity
$$
\left\| p_{0}\rho_{0} - p_{1} \rho_{1}\right\|_{1}
$$
where $p_{0} + p_{1} = 1$ and the minimization is to take place by varying over all possible values of $p_{0}$ with $0\leq p_{0} \leq 1$. That is, I want to consider the worst case scenario for the state discrimination task.
How do I find such valueof $p_{0}$? Can we only do it numerically? If so, that sucks because I want to do this for big vaules of $N$. What if we assume we can write
$$
\rho_{0} = \bigotimes_{j = 1}^{N} \rho_{0}^{j}
$$
and likewise for $\rho_{1}$? Would that help in any way?
